# 2D array - search by value and return index of array

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like

```
protected $aPermissions = [
    'read' => [
        'show'
    ],
    'update' => [
        'edit',
        'editProfilePicture'
    ]
];
```

and I want to get the array key for the sub-array ('read', 'update') by a value to possibly find within the sub-array. So searching for 'edit' would return 'update', whereas 'show' would return 'read'.

I tried PHP's array_search function (also recursively, in a loop), but didn't manage to get this to work. What's the best approach to achieve what I want?

Comment: Will the array ever nest deeper?

Comment: @Andreas in my use case: no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `array_filter` to loop thru the array and only include sub array that contains the `$search` string. Use `array_keys` to extract the keys.

```
$aPermissions = [
    'read' => [
        'show'
    ],
    'update' => [
        'edit',
        'editProfilePicture'
    ]
];

$search = 'edit';

$result = array_keys(array_filter($aPermissions, function( $o ) use ( $search ) {
    return in_array( $search, $o );
}));
```

`$result` will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => update
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the keys are on the first level and the values are in the second level you could do something like this:

```
$innerKeys = [
    "show",
    "edit"
];

$output = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
            if (isset($innerKeys[$innerKey])) $output[$innerKey] = $key;
        }
    }
}
```

If your problem is more complex, then you will need to give us additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` and `in_array` to get the `key`, there is no return type array it's just simple key name else null

```
$aPermissions = [
 'read' => [
    'show'
 ],
 'update' => [
    'edit',
    'editProfilePicture'
 ]
];
$searchAction = 'show';
$keyFound = '';
array_walk($aPermissions, function($value, $key) use ($searchAction, &$keyFound){
  in_array($searchAction, $value) ?  ($keyFound = $key) : '';
}); 
echo $keyFound;
```

Output

```
read
```

Answer (score 0):

Look time not used PHP, but this code should work!!

```
<?php
$a = [
    'read' => [
        'show'
    ],
    'update' => [
        'edit',
        'editProfilePicture'
    ]
];


$tmp = array_keys($a);
$searchterm = 'edit';
for($x =0 ; $x < count($tmp); $x++){
    if(in_array($searchterm,$a[$tmp[$x]])){
        echo $tmp[$x];
    }

}
```